# Weblogic Datasource Reset Removal

Tags: weblogic

Any changes in Database packages and procedure does require datasource reset to take effect of the change.

Changing the initial capacity and minimum capacity to 0, does it require to reset the Weblogic Datasource.

Please share your thoughts.
I want to avoid reset process in Weblogic and share your views.

Comment: I do not really understand why you change the capacity of your connection pool after updating your database. Anyway, if you realy need to reset all connections from the connection pool you can do this with the admin console or with a wlst script. See the WLS MBean reference and the JDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBean  mbean for details. It has a reset method that close and reopen all its connections

Comment: Thanks!...changing capacity to 0 indicates, server will not hold any connection in the pool ...so all connection will be created on the fly and no reset required...

Comment: Ok, but you can have bad performance if you open and close jdbc connextions everytimes the application requires it. Reseting the connection pool after any database upgrade/change can resolve your issue